# python - need help calling awk and sed in python

Tags: python, awk, sed

I tested following command on bash(Linux) and it works fine:

```
awk '/string1\/parameters\/string2/' RS= myfile | grep Value | sed 's/.*"\(.*\)"[^"]*$/\1/'
```

Now I have to call it in a python script, while string1 and string2 are python variables.

I tried it with os.popen but I didn't figure out how to concatenate the characters.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Could you post the code you wrote so we can comment on that?

Comment: Why are you using awk/sed/grep instead of doing this in Python with the `re` module? If you included a minimal working example and/or a description of the actual problem you're trying to solve, you'll have more success here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [replace shell pipeline](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) with Popen:

```
from subprocess import PIPE,Popen
from shlex import split

p1 = Popen(split("awk /string1\/parameters\/string2 RS=myfile"), stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "Value"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
p3 = Popen(split("""sed 's/.*"\(.*\)"[^"]*$/\1/'"""), stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p2.stdout.close() # Allow p2 to receive a SIGPIPE if p3 exits.

output = p3.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: thank you, your solution is working for me(except p3) but I'm confident that I will figure out the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) with the variables being substituted into the command using format():

```
cmd = """awk '/{}\/parameters\/{}/' RS= myfile | grep Value | sed 's/.*"\(.*\)"[^"]*$/\1/'""".format('string1', 'string2')
cmd_output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```

But note the warnings regarding the use of `shell=True` in the referenced documentation.

An alternative is to set up the pipeline yourself using `Popen()`:

```
import shlex
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

awk_cmd = """awk '/{}\/parameters\/{}/' RS= myfile""".format('s1', 's2')
grep_cmd = 'grep Value'
sed_cmd = """sed 's/.*"\(.*\)"[^"]*$/\1/'"""

p_awk = Popen(shlex.split(awk_cmd), stdout=PIPE)
p_grep = Popen(shlex.split(grep_cmd), stdin=p_awk.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p_sed = Popen(shlex.split(sed_cmd), stdin=p_grep.stdout, stdout=PIPE)

for p in p_awk, p_grep:
    p.stdout.close()

stdout, stderr = p_sed.communicate()
print stdout
```

Comment: thank you for your response, I use python 2.6.6 so I'm not able to use check_output, the second solution also didn't work for me, but maybe I made a mistake so I'll  check it again. 
Thank you anyway!

Comment: You've already accepted Padraic's answer (nothing wrong with that) which also uses `subprocess.Popen()`. My alternative solution is basically the same and should also work.